# sql union sum against a distinct description field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL:

```
select  distinct cat, sum(cnt)
from
(
select distinct prcIncidentManagement.CallCategory cat, count(eFolder.eFolderName) cnt
from prcIncidentManagement
inner join eFolder
on prcIncidentManagement.EFOLDERID=eFolder.eFolderID
group by prcIncidentManagement.CallCategory

union all

select distinct prcRequestFulfilment.CallCategory cat, count(eFolder.eFolderName) cnt
from prcRequestFulfilment
inner join eFolder
on prcRequestFulfilment.EFOLDERID=eFolder.eFolderID
group by prcRequestFulfilment.CallCategory
) results
order by 1
```

I am finding it difficult to sum both total and group it against the call category as the error message is as follows:

> Column 'results.cat' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Anyway around this?

Comment: You need a top-level GROUP BY too.

Comment: It is a very, very rare thing to have both DISTINCT *and* aggregation  (GROUP BY, SUM) in a query. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why is GROUP BY not enough? Why do you think you must use DISTINCT on the aggregated results?

Comment: What are you actually trying to count here? It *looks* like you are merely counting how many records are in prcIncidentManagement and prcRequestFulfilment for a category. Is that it or is there more behind it?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `distinct` and add a `GROUP BY` in the outer query:

```
select  cat, sum(cnt)
from
(
    select prcIncidentManagement.CallCategory cat, count(eFolder.eFolderName) cnt
    from prcIncidentManagement
    inner join eFolder
    on prcIncidentManagement.EFOLDERID=eFolder.eFolderID
    group by prcIncidentManagement.CallCategory
    union all
    select prcRequestFulfilment.CallCategory cat, count(eFolder.eFolderName) cnt
    from prcRequestFulfilment
    inner join eFolder
    on prcRequestFulfilment.EFOLDERID=eFolder.eFolderID
    group by prcRequestFulfilment.CallCategory
) results
GROUP BY cat
order by 1;
```

When you add and aggregate function, you can select extra columns that is not in the group by clause nor in an aggregate function.

Also there is no need for `DISTINCT` with an aggregate function in the subqueries, because it is useless, as the `group by` will give you distinct columns with an aggregate function to aggregate the other columns for each group, so you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that `eFolderName` is never `NULL` and that `eFolderId` has proper foreign key relationships (which are both very reasonable assumptions), then you can simplify the query by removing the underlying joins in the subqueries:

```
select cat, sum(cnt)
from ((select im.CallCategory as cat, count(im.eFolderID) as cnt
       from prcIncidentManagement im
       group by im.CallCategory
      ) union all
      (select f.CallCategory as cat, count(im.eFolderID) as cnt
       from prcRequestFulfilment f
       group by f.CallCategory
      ) 
     ) results
group by cat
order by cat;
```